# ONLY Show annotations for venues within radius

Tags: swift, firebase, mapkit, mkannotation, clcircleregion

I'm trying to only show the annotations for locations nearest to my user. I have all the locations already saved to firebase and now I'm just trying to retrieve them and populate the Map and TableView with only the locations around the user. I've tried GeoFire and a few others but, I'm sure I'm not doing this right. Could any one help?

[image: Db setup]

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Set up Map
            mapView.delegate = self
            mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingMode.follow

            // Setup TableView
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self

            //Pulls TableData for UITableView
            DataService.ds.REF_VENUE.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                self.posts = [] // THIS IS THE NEW LINE

                if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                    for snap in snapshot {
                        if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                            let key = snap.key
                            let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                            self.posts.append(post)
                        }

                        //Populates Map with annotations.
                    if let locationDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                        let lat = locationDict["LATITUDE"] as! CLLocationDegrees
                        let long = locationDict["LONGITUDE"] as! CLLocationDegrees
                        let title = locationDict["NAME"] as! String
                        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
                        _ = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.20, longitudeDelta: 0.20))

                        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
                        annotation.title = title.capitalized
                        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)


                        }
                    }
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
```

Here is how I set up my table:

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailCell", for: indexPath) as? PostCell {
    let cellData = posts[indexPath.row]

    cell.configureCell(post: cellData)
        return cell
    } else {
        return PostCell()
    }
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "previewSegue", sender: post)
}
```

Comment: are you saving lat and longitude values in your database of different locations ? if yes , you can make your result as using Comparators like get all data at once means all objects and now set a range from user current position and compare that range to dataSnapshot objects latitude and longitude and populate data

Comment: No they are in the same location.

Comment: I updated the code to show how I have it set up

Comment: as I see latitude and longitude values are there in Db and your current location , so you just want to populate TableView with the values from DB that have same Latitude and longitude that matched with current user location is it ?

Comment: I want to populate the map and table with location within 1km or 1mile of the user.

Comment: you can do it by comparing values of dictionary returning with range of 1 km , offline mode and then populate the table and map , let me try to write some reference code

Comment: @iOSGeek alright Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Can I please have Your Xcode project so I can try writing code ? if possible , it will be bit easy for me

Comment: https://github.com/ATrueNovice/g2g/tree/icons

Comment: Have you got a chance to take a look at the code? @iOSGeek

Comment: Sorry being late I was stucked somewhere in work. I am looking at your code now  and I am trying to find a solution, thanks for waiting

Comment: Hi I tried some code in your project and I Tried to compare venue latitude and longitude with the user current lat and longitude values , I have a query is there any venue that is located in Distance about 10 km ? if you want I can share the Vc code file in which I had tried code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As because my location is different from your location. I tested it on device and result was like distance from my location and your venue location was a large about 3K . so you can use that code file and check it in your device it will help.

1) I had replaced your didload Function for now as a different func and calling it in DidUpdateLocation of maps

2) used //iosGeek as a comment above lines of code where I inserted code in file.

3) for now I am not populating data in map or table because of location difference

```
Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz8kF1Gedr7fNThTbTFZY1Q3LVk
```

Have a look at this function in your FeedVc

1) Please test it on a Device to get the location difference

2) Print location in console to check if its coming true

3) print self.postdata in If else condition to check what is coming as output

```
    if snapshot.exists(){
        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshot {

                //Here I just used your snapshot to filter data
                self.postData = snap.value as! [String : AnyObject]
                //calculating distance here with custom function made
                let distance = self.calculateDistancxe(userlat: self.userLatt, userLon: self.userLonn, venueLat: self.postData["LATITUDE"]! as! CLLocationDegrees, venueLon: self.postData["LATITUDE"]! as! CLLocationDegrees)
                //if Distance is less Than or equal to 2 km 
                let aa : Int = Int(distance)!
                if (aa <= 2){

                     //if yes , add *self.postData* in a new Dictionary or Array

                    print("*********\(self.postData)")
                    //time to use that postdata in a dict or array from which you will populate data in TableView
                }
                else{
                    //if condition don't satisfy
                    print("noting \(distance)")
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment if still any issue occurs

Comment: I’m going to check now,

Comment: Unfortunately, it didnt work. No coordinates popped up. Give me some test locations to use and I'll put them in.

Comment: I hadn't populated data in your tableView Array used I just wrote some code there which will result output and you had to use it appending in a array and populate that array to TableView , getting my point or I should modify some code for more reference ?

Comment: Please more reference. Im not sure of the solution.

Comment: one more thing I am not populating any data for now in the code , if you want I can write that too and share with you. if you still face any issues feel free to comment I will try to help you out in it . Thanks :)

Comment: Try this updated File - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz8kF1Gedr7feVV2Y3ZYQVlhNVU

Comment: It doesn't seem like I'm getting anything. I've pulled up the code but, only the user annotation comes up. I'll try to tweak it but, I'm not sure that I quite got it yet.

Comment: Okay So can I know what exact output you are getting now ? Getting Annotations and details in Table used ? when distance is in Range ?

Comment: Right now, No annotations show up but, the table is populated with all of the locations.

Comment: okay I will create a sample project according to my location and let you know the result

Comment: If you have some time, we can connect via skype.

Comment: Hey! I got the map to populate! I just can't get the tableView cell to populate. Could you help?

Comment: yes sure , I will help you for sure , So please send me updated code so I can see , sorry I was not available for a long time

Comment: Yes please! Ive been at it a couple days now and with this part done, my app is done.

Comment: I marked the changes: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_abJdWevk3wMGVUYWpuX09YQXM